# magento api 2 create product error

Tags: magento2, rest-api, c#

I have used C# to call magento rest API to create a new product (magento version 2.2.5)

this is the body data:

```
{
  "product": {
  "id": 0,
  "sku": "MS-Champ11",
  "name": "Champ Tee11",
  "attribute_set_id": 9,
  "price": 110,
  "status": 1,
  "visibility": 4,
  "type_id": "simple",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "weight": 5,
  "extension_attributes": null,
  "product_links": null,
  "options": null,
  "media_gallery_entries": null,
  "tier_prices": null,
  "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "description",
        "value": "Test Description"
      }
    ]
  },
  "save_options": false
}
```

this is my C# code:

```
public string CreateProduct(Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = CreateRequest("/rest/V1/products", Method.POST, Token);
            var prod = new ProductModel();
            prod.Product = product;
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prod, Formatting.Indented);
            request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = Client.Execute(request);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return "Succeed";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Failed";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I tried many time but it was always responding error "BadRequest"

```
{"message":"Invalid product data: %1","parameters":["Invalid attribute set entity type"]}
```

what was i doing wrong? please help me.

Comment: Please check `"attribute_set_id": 9,`  this `9` is exist in magento.

Comment: yahoo. It's the cause of error, thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Magento Every product is assigned to a specific attribute set.
2. New Attribute set can be created by logging into Magento Admin ->
   Stores -> Attributes -> Attribute Set and then click Add attribute set button, fill the form and save it.
3. Information about Attribute Set and attribute_set_id can be found in database table eav_attribute_set.(select attribute_set_id from eav_attribute_set where attribute_set_name = 'Name of the Attribute Set where you want to create product';)
4. Use that attribute set id in your API request.